# What should be the context parameter for ContextCompat.getDrawable( )?

Tags: java, android, android-context

I use it in setOnClickListeneraccording to an another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182472/what-is-the-alternative-getdrawable-for-api-16-or-how-to-use-it)

like this :

```
  start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                start.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable( this,R.drawable.buttonstop));
```

parameter this is wrong 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in class named `MainActivity` you can use:

### In Kotlin:

```
this@MainActivity
```

e.g.

```
button.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Hello!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
})

// Or in shorter way:
frame_layout.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Hello!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

### In Java:

```
MainActivity.this
```

e.g.

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(A.this, "Hello!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

// Or in shorter way:
button.setOnClickListener(v -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v.getContext()` to get the `Context` associated with that `View`.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
this
```

in the onclicklistener will reference the listener you should use

```
MainActivity.this or getActivity()
```